# Show message in html when successed add user with angularjs+codeigniter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, codeigniter

I use codeigniter and angularjs in my app. When I add new person in angular form I'm receving message from codeigniter controller if insert person is success/failure. Block of code from angular controller:

```
request.success(function (data) {
    $scope.patientForm.$setPristine();
    $rootScope.message = data; //0 - ok, 1-fail
    if($scope.message)
        // some code
});
```

How can I show information in `div` or `p` in `html` when `$scope.message = 0` and hide this message after some time?
I know I must use ng-show but I dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-show this way :

```html
<p ng-show="!message">Information text</p>
```

It will show the p element when the expression inside `ng-show` is truthy. In this case, it will show when `message` is falsy. So when `$scope.message` has its value set to `0`, the p element will show.

To hide the message after some time, you can use the $timeout angular service as follow :

```js
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.message = newvalue;
}, 3000);
```

This will change `$scope.message`'s value after 3000 milliseconds.

If you use $timeout, don't forget to inject it in your controller.

Comment: Thank you! I  expected such a response!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use ng-show in HTML code, for exemple :

```
<div ng-show="message == 0"> your information here</div>
```

Comment: can you explain why/how this solution works or give a reference where the questioner can look it up?

Comment: ok it's work ;). How about show this but in specific time? Show popup div and fancy hide it in 5 seconds?

Comment: here is a link of the official angularJS doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf
To hide it 5 second later, you can use $timeout : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout